# Calling and adding element to Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to call the method `locationObj` in `public GameBoard` so that I can add a new element to it. I'm not sure how/where to call it within the line `squares.add(square);`.

```
public static void LocationObj()
    {
      ArrayList<Integer> squares = new ArrayList(16);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MyWorld.
     * 
     */
    public GameBoard()
    {    
        // create canvas 
        super(4, 4, 50); 

        //populate gameboard with x randomly placed objects

        // create object
        GameSquare square = new GameSquare(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            int x = Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(3);
            int y = Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(3);
            addObject(square, x, y);
            squares.add(square);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your method `LocationObj` achieve? All it does is create a list which is instantly gobbled by garbage collection. Why are you trying to access that list in your constructor?

Comment: I wanted to add the new object to the list so I can keep track of all of their positions as they're created.

Comment: @JaedynO But squares is of type `Integer`...given the code snippet, this is a bewildering question.

Comment: I'm trying to save the positions/coordinates of the objects. Which type should I be using for that?

Comment: @JaedynO The object you're trying to add is of type `GameSquare`.

Comment: Hard to make a recommendation without a better overview of the game you're trying to create, but one solution would be to add `x` and `y` coordinates to the game piece itself so you can query it directly. You would then only have to provide a reference to the game piece in each square. Really, you should just give a better description of what you're trying to do so that the correct path is more clear.

Comment: @mre oh okay, that makes sense